# $\int_{K} (z+1)\log (z+1) dz$, where $ K=\partial D(0,3)$, exist?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-integration

Does the integral $\int_{K} (z+1)\log (z+1) dz$, where $ K=\partial D(0,3)$, exist? If the answer is yes, what is it's value?
I see that $f(z)=(z+1)\log (z+1)$ is not continuous at the point $-3$ and we know by definition of curve integral that $f$ must be continuous on the Image of the curve. Any help please?

Comment: The problem is in the ambiguity of the definition as the integral is multivalued so you have to chose a specific branch; the function is integrable (has a jump discontinuity wherever you cut the branch) so it exists but value depends on branch

Comment: I break my curve $K$ on $K_1,K_2$ upper hemisphere and under hemisphere.
Then I compute those integrals by finding the function $F(z)=\dfrac{(z+1)^2}{2}(\log (z+1)-\dfrac{1}{2})$ such that $F'=f$ on $K_1$ and on $K_2$. And then I find the value of this integral. But $F$ cannot take the value -3. Should I compute them by definition?

Comment: @Conrad I change plan. I compute the line integral approximately. Roughly speaking, I take two points $a$ and $b$ closely on $-3$, $a $ on upper hemisphere and $b$ on under hemisphere, and I consider the curve $\gamma_b^a$ which conect those to points and then I compute the limit as $a,b\to -3$ of $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma_b^a} f(z)ds$. This limit is the value of the first line integral. Am I right?

Comment: What is your definition of a contour integral? If it requires continuity of the integrand on the curve, then you're out of luck. If it allows "improper" contour integrals, then what you are doing looks OK.

Comment: @zhw. Yes, It requires continuity of the integrand on the curve. However, if $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ is a partial continuous function [ i.e there exist $t_0=a<t_1<\dots<t_{n-1}<b=t_n$ such that $f$ on $(t_{i-1},t_i),\ \forall i$ is continuous and also $f$ extended continuously on $[t_{i-1},t_i],\ \forall i,$ , thus there exist curves $\gamma_i\colon [t_{i-1},ti]\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\gamma_i(t)=f(t),\ \forall\ t\in(t_{i-1},t_i),\ i=1,\dots,n$], then we define 
$$\int_a^b f(t)dt=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} \gamma_i(t)dt. $$

Comment: Above you should have $f\circ \gamma$ in various places, not $f.$

Comment: @zhw.  I know this I just right the general piece of the theory. In my exercise $f(t)$ is $(2e^{it}+1) \log (2e^{it}+1) i2e^{it},\ t\in [0,2\pi]$

Comment: its $f\circ \gamma \cdot \gamma'$